# Spyder 3 kernel needs to be restarted after each execution

Tags: 16.04, kernel, spyder

I am using spyder3 on ubuntu 16.04 as an IDE for python programming. The problem with spyder3 is when I run my program for the first time, it runs well and the second time I run it shows kernel busy forever, but does not actually do any computation. I need to restart the kernel and then it works gain. But I have to do this for each execution of a program which is not a good practice. I removed and installed spyder3 again, but didnot solve my problem. I will be grateful if anyone can help me to solve this issue.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

- open `Spyder` and then click `Tools`
- then click `Reset Spyder to factory defaults`.

If it doesn`t help, try this instead:

- open the terminal
- then enter `sudo pip install -U spyder`.

Comment: The second method finally worked. Thank you very much :-) @enigma